# Show search matches in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

Currently I see, that search window shows the method name where sought text found and the number of matches:

[image]

Is it possible to display matches itself, or their excerpts? I remember I have seen this in some IDE and was sure it was Eclipse. But currently I see none.